# converting time data from unicode in pandas

Tags: datetime, unicode, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column that consists of time data with minutes and seconds like this
22:15, 19:43 etc.  I need to convert it so I can do some calculations with it.  The fact the data is in unicode is making this task more difficult.

Comment: can u show what u are trying to do and what error u have? are these timedeltas? strings?

Comment: if i could just strip out the minute part that would be good enough.

Comment: It's better provide some examples.

Comment: What the hell are pandas?

Comment: pandas is a python library http://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use datetime and timedelta to parse and do calculations.

```
In [84]: import pandas as pd

In [85]: from datetime import datetime, timedelta

In [86]: def convert(s):
             t = datetime.strptime(s, "%H:%M")
             return timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute)

In [87]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[u'22:15', u'19:43']})

In [88]: df
Out[88]:
       A
0  22:15
1  19:43

In [89]: dfc = df.applymap(convert)

In [90]: dfc
Out[90]:
          A
0  22:15:00
1  19:43:00
```

dfc holds timedelta objects and these can be used to do calculations. For example add 24 hours.

```
In [91]: dfc + timedelta(hours=24)
Out[91]:
                 A
0  1 day, 22:15:00
1  1 day, 19:43:00
```